# Cross browser compatibility issues with HTML form

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I made an input form that has horrible cross browser compatibility. I used browser specific CSS hacks to fix most of my issues but that got *really* complicated really fast and I don't want to keep going down that path.

The form is an `800px` wide text input (`785px` width + `5px` border + `10px` padding) and `100px` wide submit button, all inside a `900px` wide `div` keeping them together.

The problem is that the text input width varies by `1px` from browser to browser which causes the input button, which is located on the right of the text input, to get pushed down by the extra pixel. I fixed this for most browsers with browser specific hacks by changing the width from `785px` to `784px` but was wondering if there's something else I'm missing that's causing this.

**Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yz8hr85y/).**

**CSS:**

```
div.formdivholder {
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

div.formdiv {
    width: 900px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

input.text {
    z-index: 20;
    height: 38px;
    width: 785px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-color: #3374DC;
    border-right: 0px;
    background-color: #F0F4FA;;
    border-top-left-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}

input.submit {
    z-index: 1;
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    float: right;
    color: #F0F4FA;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #3374DC;
    border-top-right-radius: 7px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
    border-width: 0px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="formdivholder">
    <div class="formdiv">
        <form class="search" role="search" method="get" action="/searchresults.php">
            <input type="text" name="input" class="text" placeholder="Search for"> 
            <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Search"> 
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML to your question? You could also add a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to illustrate your problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yz8hr85y/ you can see the problem in FireFox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [CSS box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property, it is supported by all browsers and IE>=9. You would need to change the following (only):

```
input.text {
    height: 50px;
    width: 800px; /* OR even this: width: calc(100% - 100px)  */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    ....
}
```

Take a look in [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yz8hr85y/1/).

Definition of the property value **border-box**:

> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but
>   not the margin. This is the box model used by Internet Explorer when
>   the document is in Quirks mode. Note: Padding & border will be inside
>   of the box e.g. IF .box {width: 350px}; THEN you apply {border: 10px
>   solid black;} RESULT {rendered in the browser} .box {width: 350px;}

You can see these days people drop support to IE8, so at the start of CSS they simply put:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

(and make their life easier).

Answer (score 0):

try using % instead of pixel, should do the trick, later on you might have to do some responsive so the % will save you time on that one also